# Element-wise operations on arrays of different rank

Tags: optimization, fortran, vectorization

How do I multiply two arrays of different rank, element-wise? For example, element-wise multiplying every row of a matrix with a vector.

```
real :: a(m,n), b(n)
```

My initial thought was to use `spread(b,...)`, but it is my understanding that this tiles `b` in memory, which would make it undesirable for large arrays.

In MATLAB I would use `bsxfun` for this.

Comment: How are you using the result of the expression?

Comment: I am unsure of what you are asking. Either in-place (is that the right word here?) `a=a*spread(b,1,m)` or assigning it to a `c(m,n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result of the expression is simply being assigned to another variable (versus being an intermediate in a more complicated expression or being used as an actual argument), then a loop (DO [CONCURRENT]) or FORALL assignment is likely to be best from the point of view of execution speed (though it will be processor dependent).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the other use-case as well? I may end up with several nested loops using above answer. Regarding execution speed, the whole thing will (at some point) run on a 64-core (opteron) machine, but I assume optimizing for a specific arch would be premature.

Comment: "Processor" in Fortran terminology is a crude synonym for compiler and machine/platform.  Different compilers will optimize different things differently.  In other use cases you may still be better off, execution speed wise, manually creating an appropriate temporary variable and assigning to it, as in the answer.  But you would have to measure to be sure.